# Should a lower layer re-perform the parameters checks already performed by an upper layer?

Tags: c#, validation

This question stems from deciding which unit tests to write for a data access layer class.

Let's say we have an application splitted in a user interface layer, a business logic layer and a data access layer. The application uses Entity Framework to store the data.

It has a `User` entity with a required `Name`:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SandboxContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

This means that Entity Framework will create a `NOT NULL` column for `Name`.

To check if a `User` is valid the it uses a dedicated validator:

```
public class UserValidator
{
    public bool IsValid(User user)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Name);
    }
}
```

When a `User` has to be saved the business logic layer validates and then save it; if the `User` is not valid it's not saved and an appropriate response is returned:

```
public class UserService
{
    private readonly UserDataContext dataContext;
    private readonly UserValidator validator;

    public UserService(UserDataContext dataContext, UserValidator validator)
    {
        this.dataContext = dataContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataContext));
        this.validator = validator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(validator));
    }

    public (bool savedSuccessfully, string errorMessage) Save(User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }

        if (!this.validator.IsValid(user))
        {
            return (false, "User is not valid.");
        }

        this.dataContext.Save(user);

        return (true, null);
    }
}
```

The data access layer simply receive the `User` and persists it:

```
public class UserDataContext
{
    private readonly SandboxContext context;

    public UserDataContext(SandboxContext context)
    {
        this.context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    public User Save(User user)
    {
        EntityEntry<User> entry = context.Users.Add(user);

        context.SaveChanges();

        return user;
    }
}
```

`UserDataContext.Save(User)` could:

- throw only an `ArgumentNullException` if `user` is null;
- throw only an `ArgumentException` if `user` is not valid;
- throw both an `ArgumentNullException` if `user` is null and an `ArgumentException` if `user` is not valid;
- don't perform any check and have Entity Framework raise an exception;

Both a null and an invalid `user` will result in Entity Framework throwing an exception, an `ArgumentNullException` in the former case and a `DbUpdateException` in the latter. Technically both of these checks have already been performed by the upper layer and repeating them verbatim is code duplication.

We have two conflicting views on this internally:

- only the null check should be performed because the validation is a business logic layer concern and parameters contents must not be inspected by "precondition" checks;
- both checks should be performed because receiving a valid user is part of the method's contract;

Is there any kind of guideline, best practice, or rule of thumb about this?

Comment: It seems to me that you consider passing null to `public bool IsValid(User user)` to be a programming error, and should therefore throw an exception there rather than returning `false`. The question is, are you checking for programming errors or are you validating user-entered data? Because the response should be different for those two cases. Programming errors should engender exceptions; incorrect user-entered data should show a user-oriented error message.

Comment: @MatthewWatson that depends: having a null `user` in the upper layers is a user error (think of a model binding failure in MVC due to invalid data posted), but once that gets handled becomes a programmer error. The application layer regards a null as user error and does not perform validation, the business layer regards a null as programmer error an performs validation, and so on. The question is about lower layers re-performing (in part or in whole) every upper layer validation again.

Comment: Saying "both checks should be performed because receiving a valid user is part of the method's contract" doesn't make sense. Methods don't need to check their preconditions, that is the callers responsibility.

Comment: @Lee why do we check for null parameters in the first place instead of letting null reference exceptions happen then? Isn't that a precondition check too?

Comment: Yes you could make the case you shouldn't need to check for `null` either. Ideally you would be able to rule them out in the type system, or you could add a contract for it. Ideally you would be able to define your `User` class so that it would be impossible to construct an invalid user instance as well, but I don't know if entity framework makes that possible.